# Gson deserialize with null int can't seems to work

Tags: java, android, null, int

When i download data on the web, sometimes it works and sometime it doesn't.
And my problem is in one `int` : 
runtime: ""

runtime is an int and when i use gson on it can cause this problem :

```
01-07 21:22:57.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

and i tried to some if statement but it doesn't work.

```
public int getRuntime() {
    if(Integer.valueOf(runtime)==null){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return runtime;
    }
}
```

or even

```
public int getRuntime() {
    if(Integer.valueOf(runtime).equals(null)){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return runtime;
    }
}
```

but nothing works.

Comment: It looks like you don't understand what exceptions are, or how to handle them: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/
Hint: whatever `runtime` is, it's not anything that can be converted to an `int`. From what you posted, it looks like an empty `String`

Comment: but when data is working it's a number and not a String, that what's strange.

Comment: @Tsunaze JSON is _always_ a string, numbers are just text encoded. Much like the number 1234 you see here (in my comment :) ) is not a number but a string that could be parsed into a number.

Comment: You were right about that. I just put String instead of int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer.valueOf() expects a String representing an integer. Calling it with an empty string will [lead to an exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29). You need to test the String before parsing it as an integer:

```
int runtime;
if ("".equals(string)) {
    runtime = 0;
}
else {
    runtime = Integer.parseInt(string);
}
```

or, if you always want that runtime is 0 if the string is not a valid integer, then catch the exception:

```
try {
    runtime = Integer.parseInt(string);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    runtime = 0;
}
```

Now, it it's gson that parses the string for you, and this string is not always an integer, then the `runtime` field should not be an int, but a String. And you should parse it yourself, as shown above.

Given your question, before trying to do anything with gson and android, you should learn the basics of the Java language. You don't seem to understand the type system in Java and what exceptions are. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/

Answer (score 3):

Handle the runtime as a string, declare it as a string in the class where you are deserializing.

Then using the gson like this will handle the nulls correctly

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

This works also when serializing, normally if values are null it will just not put anything in the json to serialize.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't understand what exceptions are, or how to handle them:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions

```
public int getRuntime() {

    int i = 0;

    try {
        i = Integer.valueOf(runtime);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("runtime wasn't an int, returning 0");
    }

    return i;

}
```

Hint: whatever runtime is, it's not anything that can be converted to an int. From what you posted, it looks like an empty String

Answer (score 1):

You either need to check `runtime` first, e.g. `if( runtime.isEmpty() )` or yet better - using apache commons lang - `if( StringUtils.isBlank( runtime ))` or catch the `NumberFormatException` that is thrown.